# Using arabic characters in sparql in python?

Tags: python, sparql, arabic, rdflib

I developed my own ontology in arabic, and now i wanna do some sparql request using **rdflib** and **sparql**. The problem is when i make a request without using the Arabic language on my ontology i got answers without problems ,but when i want to do a specific request on properties using the Arabic langage i got some errors :(.

any one know how i can deal with that please. what's i'm doing wrong !!!

Here my code:

```
graph =rdflib.Graph()
filename = r'JO Ontology modified 09 june 2014 with properties.owl'
graph.load(filename, format='xml')



qres = graph.query(   
    "PREFIX OntoJO:<http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1400008538.owl#>" +
    "SELECT  ?path "  +
    "WHERE { ?lois_ordinaires  OntoJO:ministere_lord ?ministere_lord   ."+
    "?lois_ordinaires  OntoJO:a_un_chemin ?y ."+
    " ?y OntoJO:chemin ?path ."+
    "FILTER(regex(?ministere_lord,'وزارة المالية'))}", )

for row in qres:

    print row[0]
```

the errors:

```
File "C:\Users\Mehdi\workspace\My_work\Test\Recherche.py", line 38, in main
"FILTER(regex(?ministere_lord,'وزارة المالية'))}", ) 
File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\rdflib\graph.py", line 920, in query

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rdfextras-0.4-py2.7.egg\rdfextras\sparql\components.py", line 168, in __new__
return unicode.__new__(cls, value)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 0:     ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be SPARQL specific, but rather something with rdflib.  At some point, the ascii codec is trying to decode something that's not ASCII.  (It appears to be something in the rdfextras stuff.)

Comment: @Joshua it was just a problem of quote, i fixed it. thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

i found the correct syntax for that :).

i just change this line:

```
"FILTER(regex(?ministere_lord,'وزارة المالية'))}", )
```

by this one:

```
"FILTER (regex(?ministere_lord,'""" +u"وزارة المالية"+ """'))  }""" , )
```

so the sparql request is:

```
graph =rdflib.Graph()
filename = r'JO Ontology modified 09 june 2014 with properties.owl'
graph.load(filename, format='xml')

qres = graph.query(   

    """ PREFIX OntoJO:<http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1400008538.owl#>
    SELECT  ?path 
    WHERE { ?lois_ordinaires  OntoJO:ministere_lord ?ministere_lord   .
    ?lois_ordinaires  OntoJO:a_un_chemin ?y .
    ?y OntoJO:chemin ?path .      
    FILTER (regex(?ministere_lord,'""" +u"وزارة المالية"+ """'))  

    }""" , )
```